# BlueImp jQuery file upload and "<input type="file>"

Tags: jquery, file, upload, blueimp

I'm using the BlueImp jQuery file upload code and it works really well. Just one issue. In my form, I have:

```
<input type="file">
```

And, when using the code, after the file is selected, the text "No file chosen" remains. If I test the input on a simple page or a fiddle (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/alasdairm/7kkxwxeg/) the "No file chosen" is replaced by the chosen file name as I would expect.

Note, I can check the value of the input using:

```
document.getElementById("file").addEventListener("change", function() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("file").value);
});
```

And the value is set correctly. The problem is the input does not show the selected file - it just shows "No file chosen" - even though a file has been chosen!

I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I think you solved your problem by now, but for other people who ran into the same problem: you can add `fileInput: null` to your fileupload config. Its not documented in the documentation but in the code:

```
// The file input field(s), that are listened to for change events.
// If undefined, it is set to the file input fields inside
// of the widget element on plugin initialization.
// Set to null to disable the change listener.
fileInput: undefined,
```